# Radio button not working properly when added with java to jsp page

Tags: java, arrays, jsp

I amended a successfully working java-script to make it work in jsp with java. However, its not working as per expectation, here in jsp I am dynamically creating rows based on java hashmap input. Its giving me issues in jsp, but in html + javacsript its working as expected.

So basically, when I try to make a selection. The selection jumps from one row to another and I can't make 3 different selections. Sharing screenshot as well for reference.

PS: this is not html issue, and pardon my syntax issues if in jsp, as I am new to jsp. I spent many hours trying to fix this, if you can fix the jsp snippet I would be grateful to you!

This is my jsp snippet:

```
        <tr align="left">
        <td align="left"> <%out.println( tempsysDetails1.getCategory().get(i)); %> </td>
        <td align="left"> <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions_' + i + '[]" value="0" id="inlineRadio0"' + 
        $bean{tempsysDetails1.getSystemStatus().get(i)))== '0' ? ' checked="checked"' : '' )} + '><font color="black">Grey &emsp;</font><label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions_' + i + '[]" value="1" id="inlineRadio1"' + $bean{tempsysDetails1.getSystemStatus().get(i)))== '1' ? ' = 1 ? ' checked="checked"' : '') + 
        '><font color="green">Green &emsp;</font><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions_' + i + '[]" +  id="inlineRadio2" value="2"' +  
        ($bean{tempsysDetails1.getSystemStatus().get(i)))== '2' ? ' checked="checked"' : ''  ) +  '><font color="yellow">Yellow &emsp;</font></label><label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions_' + i + '[]" id="inlineRadio3" value="3"' + 
        $bean{tempsysDetails1.getSystemStatus().get(i)))== '3' ? ' checked="checked"' : '') + '> <font color="red">Red</font></label></td>  
        <td align="left"><input type="text" id= "comments[i]" class="form-control name_list" placeholder="<%out.println(tempsysDetails1.getComments().get(i)); %> ">  </td>

    </tr>
```

This is my working javascript + html.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var appStatus = [{
  "category": "Overall Status",
  "status": "0"
 }, {
  "category": "System Availability",
  "status": "1"
 }, {
  "category": "Whatever",
  "status": "2"
 }];
 var tr;
 for (var i = 0; i < appStatus.length; i++) {
   tr = $('<tr/>');
   tr.append("<td>" + appStatus[i].category + "</td>");
   tr.append('<tr id="row' + i + '"><td><input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions_' + i + '[]" value="0" id="inlineRadio0"' + 
   (appStatus[i].status == '0' ? ' checked="checked"' : '') + 
   '><font color="black">Grey &emsp;</font><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions_' + i + '[]" value="1" id="inlineRadio1"' + 
   (appStatus[i].status == '1' ? ' checked="checked"' : '') + 
   '><font color="green">Green &emsp;</font><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions_' + i + '[]" id="inlineRadio2" value="2"' + 
   (appStatus[i].status == '2' ? ' checked="checked"' : '') + 
   '><font color="yellow">Yellow &emsp;</font></label><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions_' + i + '[]" id="inlineRadio3" value="3"' + 
   (appStatus[i].status == '3' ? ' checked="checked"' : '') + '> <font color="red">Red</font></label><td></tr>');
   //tr.append("<td>" + "<input>" + appStatus[i].comments + "</input>" + "</td>");
   tr.append("<td>" + '<tr id="row' + i + '"><td><input type="text" id="appStatus[i].comments" name="appStatus[i].comments" placeholder="Comments" class="form-control name_list" required' + "</td>");
   $('table').append(tr); }


 $('#result').on('click', function() {
  var new_status = [];
  $('.table tbody tr').each(function() {
   new_status.push({
    category: $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text(),
    status: $(this).find(':radio:checked').val()
   });
  });

  console.log(new_status);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Comments</th>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: I think there are some sintax errors on your jsp code!

Comment: This line '$bean{tempsysDetails1.getSystemStatus().get(i)))== '1' ? ' = 1 ? ' checked="checked"' : '')' does not have a closing `}`

Comment: and where is `$beans` defined? Are you trying to use JSTL?